# Unallocated space isn't seen by Windows XP setup

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, usb, gparted, windows-installation

I'm trying to install Windows XP on a TravelMate 7530 laptop. I used WinSetupFromUSB to make an bootable USB installation disk.

The problem occurs when the installation is started. The step where destination partition is chosen, it shows 0 for unallocated space and a C:/ for 2GB, which is actually the USB stick itself.

There seems to be no sign of the hard disk. Any ideas what could be tried?

I deleted all partitions with PartedMagic. However, it's still showing 0 for unallocated space.

I've also created an NTFS primary partition with PartedMagic and it's still not seen by the setup.

Update: If root (hd0, 0) is changed to root (hd1, 0), then grub4dos complains "Filesystem type is ntfs, partition type 0x07 configfile /winsetup.lst" Error 15: File not found

That is, it now finds the harddisk (hd1) but it now tries to find the winsetup.lst in the empty primary ntfs partition instead of the USB stick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like SATA drivers are not found. One thing to check is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6lPj998GXXo&feature=youtube_gdata_player or pressing F6 when prompted during Windows XP setup

Comment: Changed the SATA mode from AHCI to IDE helped. I also used nLite to slip TravelMate's SATA drivers to the XP installation files.